# why is it that property has to be public if it is a display member

Tags: c#, properties, public, internal

I have class with its object properties marked "internal". There is no accessibility issues and across the project all members can access them. But if I have set any of those properties to DisplayMember of any GUI component, then it has to be marked "public" to work properly. Else, say a listbox, displays the object's ToString() as the items. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the databinding functionality built in, only reflects on public properties.

Answer (score -2):

The internal keyword works like so:
The main purpose of the internal keyword is to let every class in your current assembly to access it. For example, if you have a .dll file and mark some of its classes internal, only the classes in that .dll can access it, and no other outside assembly or external program can access it. If you are using a GUI outside of the assembly, then you have just violated what internal is used for. Therefore, you have to make that property member public.

Though I am not an expert in c#, because I am a student, I would suggest having a "connector" class that serves as a connection to the outside members that need to access data, and the internal classes to set new data.

Comment: I suggest researching in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd74a9ww.aspx for further explanation of accessibility levels. Their example code should provide an answer to your question.